# Htaccess doesn't work on MAMP with multiple sites

Tags: .htaccess, mamp

I have 3 sites on MAMP local server but in 2 of 3, the htaccess doesnt work.
I add this code in httpd.conf (MAMP->apache):

```
NameVirtualHost * 

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "c:/MAMP/htdocs" 
ServerName localhost 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "C:\codes\Bedloop" 
ServerName local.bed.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *> 
DocumentRoot "C:\codes\apart" 
ServerName local.apart.com
</VirtualHost>
```

And this lines on windows hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1    local.bed.com
127.0.0.1    local.apart.com
```

I put on 3 pages, the same files (same page), but htacces only work on the localhost page, not in other 2. The main page work fine, but urls with rewrite rules fails.

I need to config something more?

Thx!

Comment: Thanks for detailed question, could you please do post your rules file in your question, since you mentioned your rules are not working, also you could mention errors which you are getting too in your question, thank you.

Comment: Well, how did you enable the consideration of such distributed configuration files? You have to...

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I don't post the rules because are very long file. An its exacly the same in the 3 Pages. The problem is that in the no localhost pages, mamp don't read  the htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameVirtualHost` is deprecated. Can you try these directives in your Apache vhost file and restart apache:

```sh
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName localhost 
   DocumentRoot "c:\MAMP\htdocs"
   <Directory "c:\MAMP\htdocs">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName local.bed.com
   DocumentRoot "C:\codes\Bedloop"
   <Directory "C:\codes\Bedloop">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerName local.apart.com
   DocumentRoot "C:\codes\apart"
   <Directory "C:\codes\apart">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```